# SSIS deployment to a customer site

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, ssis, bids

I am using BIDS in Visual studio 2013 to create an ssis package that a customer will run. When I am testing i use the deployment tool to deploy to our development server.

How can I create something which a customer can take and install on their integration services? The package has parameters which I set when creating a job. I need a way to set these parameters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could look into including a config file that sets the parameters for the customer.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152(v=sql.110).aspx. Thisi link (and many others) will show you how to use the stored procedures in SSISDB.catalog schema to execute your package with the parameters passed in. So, you would need to write a wrapper procedure with input parameters. Your users can call this wrapper package with parameter values of their choice. This whole setup requires project deployment, which is the preferred method in newer versions of SSIS.